# Method OnTapped does not have the correct signature

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to implement a button image, but when I put this it generates the following error

Unhandled Exception:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 28:25. Method OnTapped does not have the correct signature

```
              <Image x:Name="imagen1" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit">

                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="OnTapped" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>


  //css
 void OnTapped(object obj)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [method signature](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/) should be

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
```